# Book with solved problems on thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, resource-recommendations, education

I am working on honing my engineering thermodynamics problem solving skills at the undergraduate and graduate level. It would be much help if you could suggest me some good books with solved thermodynamics problems.

Answer (score 1):

Two series of books that I recommend to undergraduates (and use myself) for worked examples:

*Shaum's Outline Series* summarise the theory but focus on worked examples, with additional non-worked examples for extra practice.   One of the series is called *Thermodynamics for Engineers*, another is *Heat Transfer*. The Internet Archive also provides online free access to [Schaum's Theory & Problems in Thermodynamics](https://archive.org/details/TheoryProblemsOfThermodynamics).

*REA Problem Solvers* do much the same in a slightly different format.   They do a text called *Thermodynamics*.

Neither of these series will break the bank!

Comment: Link is dead :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

**Yung-Kwo Lim - Problems and Solutions in Thermodynamics and Statistical Mechanics**

which you can find here:

http://paginas.fisica.uson.mx/laura.yeomans/tc/YKL.pdf