# Book on classical thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, resource-recommendations, education

I was looking for book on classical thermodynamics. I found lot of related posts in PSE but couldn't find a book which type I was expecting. I was searching for book which covers the whole thermodynamics (not QM but it's ok if there's some knowledge of Relativity), and I want some problems in that book also (I have little bit knowledge of thermodynamics but I would like to start from the beginning)

Related

[Book with solved problems on thermodynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/205161/)

[Book recommendation for nonequilibrium thermo/stat mech](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/226929/)

[Modern textbook on statistical field theory with an emphasis on applications to non-equilibrium phenomena?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/256895/)

[References about rigorous thermodynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5614/)

[Crash course in classical thermodynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36288/)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36288/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Hi Man. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please note that res. recom. questions are restricted on Phys.SE.